# How to layout correctly to pdf

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jspdf, html2canvas

With my code I'm trying to paginate my div # printDiv in an orderly way but I can't get the expected result.
For now this is my code but the result in pdf is not correct:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        
    $("#pdfDownloader").click(function(){
    
        html2canvas(document.getElementById("printDiv"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {

                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                console.log('Report Image URL: '+imgData);
                var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4',true); //210mm wide and 297mm high
                doc.setFontSize(10);
                doc.setDrawColor(204, 204, 204);
                                doc.setLineWidth(1.0); 
                                doc.line(0, 20, 600, 20);
                
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
                doc.fromHTML($("#contInfoProd ul").html(),20,50);
                                doc.text(20,280, $("#footerPdf p").text(),{align:'center'});
                doc.save('sample.pdf');
            }
        });

    });
    
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<div id="printDiv">
  <h2>Logo MySite</h2>
  <div id="contInfoProd" style="display:none;">
  <ul>
  <li><b>Sku:</b><span>FR54367</span></li>
  <li><b>Position:</b><span>Front</span></li>
  <li><b>Printing size:</b><span>120x30mm</span></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="contDescProd">
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="footerPdf" style="text-align:center;display:none;">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit<br/>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit<br/>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
     </div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="pdfDownloader">Download</button>
```

This is my fiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/Jackom/jdap39gq/38/**

The result I would like to obtain is this:

[image]

How can I write my code to get this layout correctly?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What specifically goes wrong?

Comment: @isherwood I wish I could layout my html as in the photo I put. If you try my fiddle and download the pdf you will see the lyrics all messy ...